# Tiptap (Prosemirror) collab schema error for mention tags

Tags: javascript, tiptap, prose-mirror

I needed some help implementing **mentions** into real-time collab server (https://tiptap.dev/suggestions). My code is modded version of this: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/tiptap-sockets?path=server.js%3A1%3A0

I am sending these **steps** to my socket server to be applied to the previous version of the doc

```
steps.forEach((step) => {
    const result = Step.fromJSON(schema, step).apply(doc)
    doc = result.doc
})
```

And using this schema to validate the mention:

```
mention: {
  attrs: {
    id: {},
    label: {},
  },
  group: 'inline',
  inline: true,
  selectable: false,
  atom: true,
  toDOM: node => [
    'span',
    {
      class: 'mention',
      'data-mention-id': node.attrs.id,
    },
    `@${node.attrs.label}`,
  ],
  parseDOM: [
    {
      tag: 'span[data-mention-id]',
      getAttrs: dom => {
        const id = dom.getAttribute('data-mention-id')
        const label = dom.innerText.split('@').join('')
        return { id, label }
      },
    },
  ],
},
```

The frontend sends the following steps when I enter @Philip Isik,

step 1: @philip Isik

step 2: " "

These are the above steps in JSON form that the server receives:

```
    [ 
        '{"stepType":"replace","from":1,"to":2,"slice":{"content":[{"type":"mention","attrs":{"id":4,"label":"Philip Isik"},"content":[{"type":"text","text":"@Philip Isik"}]}]}}',
        
        '{"stepType":"replace","from":15,"to":15,"slice":{"content":[{"type":"text","text":" "}]}}' 
    ]
```

After step 1, the loop fails and throws

> RangeError: Position 15 out of range

So I checked the content length after step one, it said it was of length 3 when it should be of length 12 (length of @Philip Isik)

Does anyone know why this is happening? been at it for 2 days now. Any help is greatly appreciated!

TLDR:

1. So I'm sending a @Name to the server to be applied to the current version of the doc.
2. The server receives the mentioned step @Name
3. Now when it sends the next step, the step being sent is for location 6 (@Name is of length 5, so 5+1th=6th pos)
4. Here is the problem, according to tiptap/prose object, @ Name is of length 2, not 5
5. Therefore, it throws a 'Position-out-of-range error'

Comment: I do not understand what you mean, please explain more

Comment: 1. So I'm sending a @Name to the server to be applied to the current version of the doc.

2. The server receives the mentioned step @ Name 
3. Now when it sends the next step, the step being sent is for location 6 (@ Name (ignore space after @ ) is of length 5, so 5+1th=6th pos)
4. Here is the problem, according to tiptap/prose object, @ Name is of length 2, not 5
5. Therefore, it throws a 'Position-out-of-range error'

Comment: The error message is coming from [`prosemirror-model`](https://github.com/ProseMirror/prosemirror-model/blob/06a044abfe64d57e0d1c8c1a5a7a914386530b84/src/resolvedpos.js#L230) which is used in your `schema.js`

Comment: I have one suggestion bellow, not sure if it'll help but please try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `trim()` to `parseDOM` to remove whitespace as I see the issue may be related trailing space being present (`"text": " "`).

```
'{"stepType":"replace","from":15,"to":15,"slice":{"content":[{"type":"text","text":" "}]}}'
```

When tested in Chrome browser, simple HTML like this with some new-lines and spaces:

```
<span data-mention-id="test">
  @Test mention
</span>
```

returned `dom.innerText` with a trailing space at the end `@Test mention` .

Here's updated schema with `trim` added to `parseDOM`:

```
mention: {
  attrs: {
    id: {},
    label: {},
  },
  group: 'inline',
  inline: true,
  selectable: false,
  atom: true,
  toDOM: node => [
    'span',
    {
      class: 'mention',
      'data-mention-id': node.attrs.id,
    },
    `@${node.attrs.label}`,
  ],
  parseDOM: [
    {
      tag: 'span[data-mention-id]',
      getAttrs: dom => {
        const id = dom.getAttribute('data-mention-id')
        const label = dom.innerText.trim().split('@').join('') // trim removes white space around text
        return { id, label }
      },
    },
  ],
},
```

Comment: The trailing space isn't the problem. The problem is the offset length of @ mention content is always 1 and not the length of the name. Anyways I tried the code, didn't work.

Comment: The problem is with the schema.